# New Rails 4 project requiers mysql gem installed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am creating a new `rails` project without any `-d` option, but when I open it in browser it crashes with:

> Specified 'mysql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql'` to your Gemfile.

There is no mention of `mysql` adapter anywhere any the project (it's a new one) and the adapter in `database.yml` is `sqlite3`. I also tried `-d sqlite3`, no luck. Some lines of the trace are:

```
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:55:in `resolve_hash_connection'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:32:in `spec'
.
.
.
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Have you tried using -d with sqlite3?

Comment: Mention the exact error and the and what adapter you have mentioned in database.yml

Comment: I've tried `-d sqlite3`, I've also written the detail of the error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gem::LoadError: Add \`gem 'mysql'\` to your Gemfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260147/gemloaderror-add-gem-mysql-to-your-gemfile)

Comment: errors are the same, but different issues

Comment: @Aguardientico That question asks for MySQL; this one asks for SQLite.

Comment: Well, that solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Same problem on Rails 4.0.2

Comment: same issue. mysql gem is not loaded. I also tried with version mention. It not working. Any solution ...